# How to get the current process id of a dotnet core application while it is running?

Tags: .net-core, pid

I'm trying to get the processid so I can attach the **dotnet core** console application to the right process to debug in **Visual Studio 2019**:

I used the following code in the `progress.cs`. This code displays a processid but the processid is not listed in the number of **dotnet** process in Visual Studio 2019.

```
var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
Console.WriteLine($"ProcessId: {currentProcess.Id}");
```

Comment: What's the value of `currentProcess.ProcessName`?

Comment: It's the name of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version of **dotnetcore**, the **Attach to Process** will display the application name in the **process** column. So the **processid** is not necessary.